# Parts of references in bibliography missing/spelling wrong

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I have a problem with the references in my bibliography. First of all, neither URL nor "Laatst geraadpleegd op: [date]" (EN: Accessed on) are displayed for internet sources. And another problem is the case sensitivity of the sources. It works for a few sources, but most sources completely ignore the case sensitivity of the references in the bibliography file. I try to attach a reduced example of my work.

```
\documentclass{UniVieCS_Thesis} 

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[ngerman, dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}

This is a test.\footnote{\cite{DARIAHDE.2019}.} This is also a test.\footnote{\cite{Hockey.2008}.} Again, a test.\footnote{\cite{Schoch.2017}.} 
  
                                                                                                            
        
    %add your sources in the bib file and change the style here
    \bibliographystyle{chicagoa}
    \bibliography{bibliography2}

    
\end{document}
```

The references in the bibliography2-file look like that:

```
%%%%%%%%TEST%%%%%%%%%

% This file was created with Citavi 6.8.0.0

@misc{DARIAHDE.2019,
 author = {DARIAH-DE},
 year = {2019},
 title = {Notebook IntroducingMallet.ipynb},
 url = {https://github.com/DARIAH-DE/Topics},
 urldate = {10.06.2021}
}


@incollection{Hockey.2008,
 author = {Hockey, Susan},
 title = {The History of Humanities Computing},
 pages = {3--19},
 publisher = {{John Wiley {\&} Sons Ltd}},
 isbn = {9781405168069},
 series = {Blackwell companions to literature and culture},
 editor = {Unsworth, John and Schreibman, Susan and Siemens, Ray},
 booktitle = {A Companion to Digital Humanities},
 year = {2008},
 address = {Hoboken}
}


@misc{Schoch.2017,
 author = {Sch{\"o}ch, Christof and Schl{\"o}r, Daniel},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Topic Modeling Workflow in Python. Computergest{\"u}tzte literarische Gattungsstilistik (CLiGS).},
 url = {https://github.com/cligs/tmw},
 urldate = {10.06.2021}
}
```

In the image there is the wrong output. So, the citation in the document is right (with the footnotes), but the bibliography lacks URLS and the date.

[image]

[image]

The link to the documentclass can be found here: [UniVieCS_Thesis](https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-faculty-of-computer-science-university-of-vienna/whyzmtqggxzz)

Comment: The `chicagoa` bib style is not programmed to recognize, let alone process, fields called `url` and `urldate`. You either need to switch to a more recent bib style or need to edit the bib file and replace `url = {https://github.com/DARIAH-DE/Topics}, urldate = {10.06.2021}` with `note = {\url{https://github.com/DARIAH-DE/Topics}, retrieved on 10.06.2021`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a MWE to your question. The `chicagoa` bibliography style is very old, and doesn't include any functionality for handling URLs. So I would recommend switching to a more modern method of doing bibliographies like `biblatex` and using one of its number/footnote styles.

Comment: You can tell BibTeX not to change the case of something by putting extra braces around the letters whose case you want to maintain in the .bib file, e.g.,  `title = {The {H}istory of {H}umanities {C}omputing}`. But this is also in part determined by the bib style, and I'm not sure you're using the right one.